# How to route a page to a different server using Node

Tags: node.js, dns

Suppose I have a landing page for all my web apps at www.example.com. These web apps all currently have different web servers (node server scripts) running them but all of these are on the same machine. So I want www.example.com/webApp1 to point to web app 1's server, www.example.com/webApp2 to point to web app 2's server, and so on... Is there a way to do this without a redirect? I want the domain to still be www.example.com/webApp1 and not www.example.com:8008 or something like that.

Thanks

Comment: Do you have the option to have a proxy server in front?

Comment: Yes, but is this the usual way that it is done? As long as I satisfy the requirement for keeping the domain name like www.example.com/webAppX it is okay.

Comment: In my opinion, proxying would be the way to go.

Comment: By "different servers" do you mean they're on *different systems* or are they all (web) server processes running on the *same system*?

Comment: Different (web) server processes running on the same system. Will clarify in edit.